# how to package a python application for publishing in Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: python, packaging

I have a running python application, I am wondering how package it for publishing into myapps

Comment: check this https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/publish/

Comment: Thanks @New USer, but this talks about Ubuntu SDK which uses QT.. I think I need to package from python into .deb, but I can't find how.